# Data missing while sending data from central to peripheral - CoreBluetooth ios

Tags: ipad, ios8, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheralmanager

In CoreBluetooth, am trying to transfer data from central to peripheral using `writevalue: with type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse` which makes the data transfer faster. but datas getting missed in between.

i dont want to use `writevalue: with type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse` because its slower in transferring as am transmitting huge data's continuously
Help me where am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is more important ? Fast or reliable?  It sounds like your peripheral can't keep up but also, remember GATT is attribute based, not stream based so an update can be discarded if you supply a new value for an attribute before the old one had been sent

Comment: @Paulw11 i need  the both faster and no data loss , can you let me know if any rules to be followed for it.

Comment: There is a suggest approach at the bottom of this page that sounds like it might work - http://osdir.com/ml/general/2014-04/msg55620.html